# Building a Access Report from a query

Tags: ms-access

I have a query that has 3 columns: Payment Method, Count, Amount. When I try to create my report to bring in the data from the query, if a payment method has more than one in the count column it shows up as zero on my report for the count and the total. I am using the following in expression builder to bring in the data from the query:

for the number of the specific payments

```
=Sum(IIf([paymethod]="Discover",[Count],0))
```

for the total amount of all payments

```
=Sum(IIf([paymethod]="Discover",[Total],0))
```

The SQL behind the report

```
SELECT qryDailyDeposit.Count, qryDailyDeposit.Total, qryDailyDeposit.paymethod
FROM [qryTotal Deposit], qryDailyDeposit;
```

Comment: @cularis When I try to bring in my data from the query into the report, if i have 5 transactions that were made by a discover card, on my report it will populate 0 for the text boxs above. but, if I have only 1 transaction made by discover it will populate the count as one and the total for that transaction. I need it to populate any amount of transactions and the total for all of them.

Comment: What's the SQL behind the query you're binding the report to?  Is the only purpose of this report to show the amount and sum of the various payment methods?

Comment: @Banjoe yes thats the only purpose.

Comment: I just noticed, why are you joining qryTotalDeposit to qryDailyDeposit?  How are they related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your query with JOIN and Count(*) causes issues. Regardless, the following setup should guard you against unexpected results:

- Payment Methods table:

  [image]
- Payments table:

  [image]
- Query:

  [image]
- Query results:

  [image]

Now, just use the above query as datasource for your report:

- Report datasource:

  [image]
- Report preview:

  [image]

Comment: I have setup my query as stated above but, in using the example above. Discover Card and Visa would not show up on my report bc the count is greater than 0. For some reason its only the rows that have more than one in the count, that it leaves at 0

Comment: @edmon - please see my edited answer. As you could see, the report works just fine

Comment: ok, i have corrected my issue. but now when I have the information show up, it is duplicated in the details section of the report.

Comment: As far as I know, Report Detail section cannot repeat itself. So, the problem may come from the incorrect placement of the controls etc. Again, check with my screenshots above and you will not get any duplication

Comment: Does your query return correct data? Maybe it is query that "duplicates" the data?

Comment: Yes the query does. But when I click on the report it gives me 3 pages of date duplicated but everthing is doubled. So for page one I will have a count of 8, an a amount of 1500 for a cash transaction, then on page 2 i will have a count of 16, an a amount of 3000 for a cash transaction, etc.

Comment: There is **Running Sum** property of **Text Box** control (_Data_ tab). Please check if it is set to No

Answer (score 0):

Make a new query to bind to the report:

`SELECT paymethod, sum(amount) as [Amount], count(*) as [Total Payments] FROM yourTransactionTable GROUP BY paymethod ORDER BY paymethod`

Once that's bound to your report you should be able to use a query wizard to build a quick report or design your own by dragging the bound fields over.

I'm guessing the reason you're getting 0 entry text boxes is that the report is going through each row returned by the query and on rows where the paymethod isn't "Discover", for example, it just outputs 0.

Comment: if all my payment methods have 1 in the count column it will show in the text box, but if any of them have more than 1, it puts 0 in my text box for count and total.

Comment: @Banjoe - your query does not include Payment Methods that had 0 transactions. Edmon may want to display them as well.